# Install pygtk module for python2.7

Tags: python, python-2.7, pygtk

My OS is CentOS 6, which contains python 2.6.6 as default. I installed python 2.7 in /usr/local/.....

I tried to use pip to install pygtk in the first place, but it didn't work. So I decided to install it manually. I use:

```
./configure --prefix=/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages
```

The error message shows the default version is python 2.6.6, it tried to install in /usr/local/lib/python2.6/... which of course does not exit.  I also defined alias of python as python2.7, so when I type python, it will assume it's python2.7. But here it didn't work this way. Any suggestions? Thanks!

BTW:  The error message when I installed the pygtk by pip is:

Command python setup.py egg_info failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip_build_root/pygtk

Storing debug log for failure in /root/.pip/pip.log

Exception information:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip-1.5.4-py2.7.egg/pip/basecommand.py", line 122, in main status = self.run(options, args)

File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip-1.5.4-py2.7.egg/pip/commands/install.py", line 278, in run requirement_set.prepare_files(finder, force_root_egg_info=self.bundle, bundle=self.bundle)

File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip-1.5.4-py2.7.egg/pip/req.py", line 1229, in prepare_files req_to_install.run_egg_info()

File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip-1.5.4-py2.7.egg/pip/req.py", line 325, in run_egg_info command_desc='python setup.py egg_info')

File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip-1.5.4-py2.7.egg/pip/util.py", line 697, in call_subprocess % (command_desc, proc.returncode, cwd)) InstallationError: Command python setup.py egg_info failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip_build_root/pygtk
```

Comment: What does `/root/.pip/pip.log` say?

Comment: Please see the below comments